# Delete file from SFTP with dynamic name

Tags: marketing-cloud, delete, sftp

We have following use case: We will have bunch of invoices sent to SFMC SFTP, which will be attached to emails and send to customers. Each invoice name is unique, e.g. {{customerID}}_{{invoiceNr}}_Day.month_year.pdf

We have to delete the files form the SFTP after sending them out, but I could not find any process of doing this automatically. I can setup wild cards only for dates, SFMC does not accept * as text string replace.

Note: We have Delete data from DE enabled.